# SQL query multiplying SUM results when joining to multiple transaction tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm developing a report which measures cash performance based on allocation and cancellation dates. To measure this I've queried a transactions sub query which pulls back all transactions and is joined on an account number and transaction from and to dates. This is then summed up at the top of the query.

All works fine when using one sub query however I'm now having to add an extra transactions sub query; 1 to calculate actual payments from the allocation date (to cancellation date or today if value is null) and the 2nd to calculate any cancelled payments from the allocation date + 14 days (to cancellation date or today if value is null).

The first sub query works perfectly but now I've added the second it's multiplying the summed value by 8. I've had this in the past when trying to query this table twice. (Not always by 8). Any ideas?

Thanks

The sums totalling these (TEST1 works fine, TEST2 not so much) and the sub queries:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN v1.[Transaction Date1] >= dateadd(DD, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1)) 
            THEN v1.[Payments] ELSE 0 
    END) AS TEST1,
SUM(CASE WHEN v2.[Transaction Date2] >= dateadd(DD, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1)) 
            THEN v2.[Payments2] ELSE 0 
    END) AS TEST2,
```

My code:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [Account Number1], [Transaction Date1], SUM([Payments1]) AS [Payments]
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              ACCOUNTNO AS [Account Number1],
              TRANDT AS [Transaction Date1],
              CASE 
                 WHEN TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Credit' 
                    THEN TRANAMT * -1
                    ELSE TRANAMT
              END [Payments1]
          FROM 
              TRANSACTIONS t WITH (NOLOCK)
          JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONDETAILS td WITH (NOLOCK) ON td.TRANSACTIONID = t.TRANSACTIONS1
          JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONS a WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = TRANSACTIONS1
                                           AND [TRANTYPE] LIKE '%PAY%'
                                           AND [TRANAMT] <> 0
          INNER JOIN 
              ACCOUNTS na WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ACCOUNTID = ACCOUNTS1
          WHERE 
              TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Credit') v
     GROUP BY 
         [Account Number1], [Transaction Date1]) v1 ON MAINT.[ACCNO] = v1.[Account Number1]
                                                    AND MAINT.[Allocation Date] <= v1.[Transaction Date1]
                                                    AND v1.[Transaction Date1] <=  MAINT.[Transaction to date]
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [Account Number2], [Transaction Date2], SUM([Payments2]) AS [Payments2]
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              ACCOUNTNO AS [Account Number2],
              TRANDT AS [Transaction Date2],
              CASE  
                 WHEN TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Credit' 
                    THEN TRANAMT * -1
                    ELSE TRANAMT
              END [Payments2]
          FROM 
              TRANSACTIONS t WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONDETAILS td WITH (NOLOCK) ON td.TRANSACTIONID = t.TRANSACTIONS1
          INNER JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONS a WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = TRANSACTIONS1
                                           AND [TRANTYPE] LIKE '%PAY%'
                                           AND [TRANAMT] <> 0
          INNER JOIN 
              ACCOUNTS na WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ACCOUNTID = ACCOUNTS1
          WHERE 
              TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Debit') v
      GROUP BY 
          [Account Number2], [Transaction Date2]) v2 ON MAINT.[ACCNO] = v2.[Account Number2]
                                                     AND DATEADD(DD,10,MAINT.[DCA Allocation Date]) <= v2.[Transaction Date2]
                                                     AND v2.[Transaction Date2] <=  MAINT.[Transaction to date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the inner most subselect is the same in both joins, you should put it in a WITH statement at the top and then just use that twice. 
Like this:

```
WITH v_CTE
AS  
(SELECT
              ACCOUNTNO AS [Account Number2],
              TRANDT AS [Transaction Date2],
              CASE  
                 WHEN TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Credit' 
                    THEN TRANAMT * -1
                    ELSE TRANAMT
              END [Payments2]
          FROM 
              TRANSACTIONS t WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONDETAILS td WITH (NOLOCK) ON td.TRANSACTIONID = t.TRANSACTIONS1
          INNER JOIN 
              TRANSACTIONS a WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = TRANSACTIONS1
                                           AND [TRANTYPE] LIKE '%PAY%'
                                           AND [TRANAMT] <> 0
          INNER JOIN 
              ACCOUNTS na WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ACCOUNTID = ACCOUNTS1
          WHERE 
              TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Debit') 
...
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [Account Number1], [Transaction Date1], SUM([Payments1]) AS [Payments]
     FROM 
         v_CTE v
     GROUP BY 
         [Account Number1], [Transaction Date1]) v1 ON MAINT.[ACCNO] = v1.[Account Number1]
                                                    AND MAINT.[Allocation Date] <= v1.[Transaction Date1]
                                                    AND v1.[Transaction Date1] <=  MAINT.[Transaction to date]
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [Account Number2], [Transaction Date2], SUM([Payments2]) AS [Payments2]
     FROM 
         v_CTE v
      GROUP BY 
          [Account Number2], [Transaction Date2]) v2 ON MAINT.[ACCNO] = v2.[Account Number2]
                                                     AND DATEADD(DD,10,MAINT.[DCA Allocation Date]) <= v2.[Transaction Date2]
                                                     AND v2.[Transaction Date2] <=  MAINT.[Transaction to date]
```

Comment: You can do better.  You might as well post the poor person a little sql.